# LinkButton OnClick Doesn't run with data-target and data-toggle

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

In my asp.net application (using C#) I have the following link button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSelectPhoto" runat="server" Width="120" style="display:inline-block; margin:5px;"
    CausesValidation="false" 
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") + "," + Eval("Name") + "," + Eval("Description") + "," + Eval("Path") + "," +  Eval("DateCreated") %>'
    OnClick="btnSelectPhoto_Click"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#album-photo" > 

    ...

</asp:LinkButton>
```

Currently with the `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes present it doesn't seem to fire the `OnClick` event (break point never occurs).

When I remove the `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes then the event fires completely fine but I need that data-toggle and data-target to be present. Is there a way for me to call that `data-toggle` and `data-target` functionality in the code behind at the end of my `OnClick` event? Or perhaps some other solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I've added the following line of code to the end of my `OnClick` event and now everything works perfectly.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Show", "<script> $('#album-photo').modal('toggle');</script>");
```

Comment: I also added another solution if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind add the attributes at the OnInit method of the page that way they will be rendered with specified attributes and also back-end will know about them if needed.

Sample :

```
  protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        btnSelectPhoto.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "modal");
        btnSelectPhoto.Attributes.Add("data-target", "#album");
    }
```

**Edit** : As you stated this is on the ListView the solution above would also work it is a bit hacky but you can do it like this

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.ListView1.DataSource = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        this.ListView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dataList = ListView1.DataSource as IEnumerable<int>;
        var senderButton = (sender as Button);
        var data = (senderButton.NamingContainer as ListViewItem).DataItem;
        senderButton.Attributes.Add("data-x", data.ToString());
    }
```

Data is the data bound to the ListView for this template button.

Comment: I didn't mention that my link button is inside ListView ItemTemplate so it's "doesn't exist in current context"